# Random access zip file using java.util.zip

Tags: java, zip

May I know how I can randomly access a zip file and decompress an ZipEntry?

Basically I already know the files I wish to get from the zip file and do not wish to unzip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of getting the zip entry as a stream (ZipFile.getInputStream(entry));

```
    ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(entryName);
    InputStream xmlInStream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
            //process the stream- below one is for xml parsing.
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return documentBuilder.parse(xmlInStream);
```